# Recording time since last collision

Tags: unity

I am trying to record time since the last collision happened.But this is not working as I expect it to.

So, numberLimitOfCollision is equal to 0 only in the begining, 
Basically, what I am trying to achieve is increase the number of collisions by 1 if new collision occurs with in a second otherwise make the variable back to 1.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
void Update()
{
 while (collision == false && numberLimitOfCollision != 0) {
            timeSinceLastCollsiion += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                if (timeSinceLastCollsiion > 0.8 && collision == false) {
                        timeSinceLastCollsiion = 0;
                        numberLimitOfCollision = 1;
                }
             else if (timeSinceLastCollsiion < 2 && collision == true) {
            numberLimitOfCollision = numberLimitOfCollision + 1;
                        }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collider col)
{
collision = true;
}
void OnCollisionExit(Collision x)
{
collision = false;
}
```

Where I am  going wrong?

Comment: Simran, it looks like a lot of your questions are just from being inexperienced in coding. 
Your code above is a clear indication of this. I suggest you try some tutorials, and just generally expand on your programming knowledge. Learn to use the debugger to step through your code to see how it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you start a loop inside Update?

```
float lastCollisionInstant = 0; //Store last collision timing 
const float collisionInterval = 1.0f;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.name == "Enemy")
    {
            float collisionInstant = Time.time; //This collision instant

            if(lastCollisionInstant - collisionInstant < collisionInterval) //Time elapsed since last collision
                numberOfCollision += 1;
            else
                numberOfCollision = 1;

            lastCollisionInstant = collisionInstant; //Set last collision time
    }
}
```

Comment: I did use the code you have mentioned, but for some reason, the value of collisionInstannt was always 0.2 and so the difference turned down to 0 every time it was subtracted.Any idea,why did that happen?

Comment: Because you need to ignore ground collision.

Comment: @We are doing it inside the tag check of enemy, how else do I ignore the collision with ground?

Comment: Instead of the enemy put the name of gameobject you want it to work with. This will mean that all logic we have written will only work with that gameobject only.